# Error when trying to call setData(from: ) in the Cloud Firestore ios API. How can i fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

Working in Swift..

I'm trying to call .setData(from: ) to write a Codable struct to a document in the cloud firestore database as outlined in the Firebase docs here to:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects

However, I'm getting the error: "Argument labels '(from:)' do not match any available overloads"

The odd thing is I was able to build and run on the simulator once, and successfully posted a document, but now obviously the compiler is calling this error and causing the build to fail. relevant code below:

the line that is causing the build to fail:

```
do {
      try collectionRef.document(lensSet.id.uuidString).setData(from: lensSet)

    } catch let error {
      print(error)
    }
```

The Codable Struct:

```
struct LensSet: Codable, Identifiable {
  var id: UUID

  // Coding KEYS
  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id
  }
}
```

It seems like the function they are saying to call in the docs maybe doesn't exist? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Appears as if `setData(from:)` is deprecated but they forgot to update the documentation which explains why it used to work and now doesn't. I don't see the `setData(from:)` method anywhere in the current SDK either.

Comment: To answer your question of how to fix it, you must give the `setData()` method a `[String: Any]` dictionary which you can do from the struct (through a computed property within the struct that returns this dictionary) or manually (using the struct's existing properties).

Comment: Ok thanks! I guess it was too good to be true! When it worked, it was actually just this morning, so it's still a bit of a mystery, but it does seem to be gone from the docs..

Comment: Well they didn't release an update today so that's unlikely the case. And it's still in the docs in the link you provided.

Comment: In fact, I still have the old build on my simulator, and I can use it to post docs to the database! Extremely strange..

Comment: It was strange! Firebase added and extension to make crafting customer objects easier but forgot to tell us. See my answer to this question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation isn't exactly wrong, it's just incomplete in one section.

**EDIT:** for TL;DR

See the guide from Peter Friese: [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/)

For the longer explanation

Firebase added an extension to make crafting custom obects easier but didn't mention that extension in the documentation. (I assume its an extension)

The documentation on Custom Objects is an example of the code that needs the extension

Simple fix by adding this to your podfile

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
```

and then do a pod update either in terminal or cocoapods.

Then in your Class just update the imports to include that

```
import Cocoa
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

For reference the code in the docs was this

```
try db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(from: city)
```

and this

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("LA")

 docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    let result = Result {
    try document.flatMap {
       try $0.data(as: City.self)
    }
 }
```

and this line

```
.data(as: City.self)
```

and

```
.setData(from:
```

were the 'troublemakers' that needed the FirebaseFirestoreSwift

Comment: I created a comprehensive guide to using Codable with Firestore: https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/. We've also updated the documentation to include more examples for Codable.

Comment: @PeterFriese That's a brilliant guide. Fantastic. I integrated that into the answer so folks could find it faster. Thanks for writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, the easy fix is to just use both

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

and everything works.