# Swift Firebase Custom Object with Document ID

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

Is there a way to create a custom Swift Object where I assign the Firebase Document ID to a Object parameter?

Code taken from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

```
public struct City: Codable {
    let id: String // here I'd like to fill in the Document ID
    let name: String?
    let state: String?
    let country: String?
    let isCapital: Bool?
    let population: Int64?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = //Document ID
        case name
        case state
        case country
        case isCapital
        case population
    }
}
```

Getting Firebase document and creating the Object. Code also taken from Goolge Firebase link above.

````
fun getObject(){

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error retrieving document: \(error)")
        return
    }
    let result = Result {
      try document?.data(as: City.self)
    }
    switch result {
    case .success(let city):
        if let city = city {
            // A `City` value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            print("City: \(city)")
        } else {
            // A nil value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
            // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil.
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        // A `City` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
        print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
    }
}
}```
````

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an even easier way to achieve this using the Codable support we added to Firestore recently:

Add the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` pod:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'MyAwesomeApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyAwesomeApp
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
end
```

```swift
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
struct City: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
  let name: String
  let state: String
  let country: String
  let isCapital: Bool
  let population: Int64

  // you only need CodingKeys if your attribute names in Firestore differ from the property names on your struct!
}
```

By using the `@DocumentID` property wrapper, you tell Firestore's Codable support that you want it to map the document's ID to the `id` field. Also note that - as the `City` struct implements `Identifiable` - you will be able to use it in a SwiftUI `ListView`.

Then, in your view model, use `queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as:)` to fetch and map data in a typesafe way:

```
import FirebaseFirestore

class CitiesViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var cities = [City]()

  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?

  deinit {
    unregister()
  }

  func unregister() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
    }
  }

  func fetchData() {
    unregister()
    listenerRegistration = db.collection("cities").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("No documents")
        return
      }

      self.cities = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> City? in
        return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: City.self)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have that documented. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021668/error-when-trying-to-call-setdatafrom-in-the-cloud-firestore-ios-api-how-ca/61028935#61028935)

Comment: @Simon This is a great answer with a few things to consider; it will omit the actual documentID (the key) of each document, so the documentID *will also have to be stored as a field within each Firestore document* which I don't believe was your intended behavior in the question. It works as shown but can be somewhat redundant. Also, keep in mind that with this code, any changes will reload the entire list of cities instead of handling a specific event - that will drive costs up. In other words, if there are 10,000 cities, and if the population is updated on one city, they will all reload.

Comment: I think self.books should be self.cities?

Comment: You're right @Jay - `self.books` should be `self.cities` - I've fixed that. I've also addressed your remark about the `id` property in your previous comment. When I first wrote the answer, I forgot to add the `@DocumentID` property wrapper - which is one of the key features of Firestore's Codable support. Now that it is added, this code should meet @Simon's requirements.

Comment: I’m trying to figure out how to use @DocumentID when my model (for architectural reasons) needs to be a class. I keep getting Id back as nil. Has any one encountered this?

Comment: This pod cannot be added to new Xcode projects:

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseFirestore (= 7.9.0, ~> 7.9.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 7.9.0, which depends on
      FirebaseFirestore (~> 7.9.0)

    FirebaseFirestoreSwift was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
      FirebaseFirestore (>= 1.6.1, ~> 1.6)

Comment: Does this require that an `id` property be a `var`? It seems like in many cases `id`s should be `let`s.

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question takes the information from a document and maps it to a city object. If you want to assign the documentId to that city object, this will do it

```
switch result {
case .success(let city):
    if var city = city {
        city.docId = document!.documentID
        print("City: \(city)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
case .failure(let error):
    print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
}
```

Note `var city` so you can then assign the documentID to it with

```
city.docId = document!.documentID  //please safely unwrap optionals (!)
```

and don't forget this

```
public struct City: Codable {
   var docId = ""    //needs to be a var
   let name: String
```

Comment: Does work. Thank you so much for your contribution!

Comment: I'd recommend using Firestore's Codable support, which allows you to perform typesafe mappings from Firestore documents to Swift structs.