# Firebase+SwiftUI. Cannot convert value

Tags: firebase, swiftui

When I try to run the below code, the error I see is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'String'

on the return line. How do I resolve this error? This function is trying to fetch data from document so that I can edit. Thanks!

```
db.collection("routines").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: currUser?.uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            self.routines = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Routine in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let id = data["id"]
                let routine = data["routine"] as? String ?? ""
                return Routine(id: id, routine: routine)
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
Changed id to let id = String(describing: data["id"]!) to make it work. Curious to hear if this is even the right thing to be doing though!

**EDIT based on answer below**
Tried your suggestion, but can't seem to make it work. The view doesn't end up showing any of my routines.

Model

```
struct Routine: Identifiable, Codable {
   @DocumentID var id: String?
   var routine: String
   var uid: String

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id
      case routine
      case uid
   }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class RoutinesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var routines = [Routine]()
    var db = Firestore.firestore()
    let currUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("routines").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: currUser?.uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            self.routines = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Routine? in


     return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Routine.self)
        }
```

View

```
List {
    ForEach(viewModel.routines) { routine in
        HStack {
            Text("\(routine.routine)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data()` method returns a dictionary that maps form `String` to `Any` - see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-yQeAf3bLE) for a detailed explanation.

Looking at your [data model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274356/swiftui-firebase-not-able-to-edit-row), I noticed that you've got an `id` field on all documents that is equivalent to the document ID. This is actually not required, as you can use the document ID directly:

```swift
let id = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
```

However, I'd recommend using Firestore's Codable support to make this even easier:

```swift
let routine = try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Routine.self)
```

To make this work, you'll need to add the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`, and make your model `Codable`.

Read more about this in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432255/281221), and [this](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data/) and [this article](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/), respectively.

Comment: Thanks Peter for answering my many questions! I tried implementing this, but can't seem to get the view to read the data. Please see above edited question.

Comment: Did you call the fetchData function?

Comment: Yes! Did so onAppear as tutorials said.

Comment: Can you share the log output? Also, try stepping through the view model code and see where it stops working as expected. (i.e. does the querSnapshot contain any documents, does the mapping fail, etc.)

Comment: Hi @DavidLau - if this is still an issue, please provide more details (e.g. log output, or a link to your Github repo so people can take a closer look).