# Firestore @DocumentID field overrides all @DocumentID in nested types

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Issue with Firestore and Swift.
It is convenient to write/reade `Codable` items in collection with `setData(from: item)`.

Like this:

```
    func updateOrAddItem() {
        if let documentID = item.id {
            do {
                item.modified = .now
                try db.collection(FBKeys.CollectionPath.users).document(userID).collection(Item.collectionName).document(documentID).setData(from: item)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Suppose we have type `CartElement` with a subtype `Item`.

```
struct CartElement: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id = UUID().uuidString
    var item: Item
    var quantity: Double
    var comment: String
}
```

```
struct Item: Codable, Identifiable {
    // !!!: `@DocumentID` is overwriten with actual DocumentID on save, i.e. `setData()`
    @DocumentID var id = UUID().uuidString
    // !!!: If we are ofline it will be `nil` after save
    @ServerTimestamp var modified: Date?
    var modifiedBy: String = ""
    var title: String
    var price: Double
}
```

Elements of these types are stored in Firestore collection. This is why we take advantage of `@DocumentID` property wrapper. It gives us an opportunity to get a particular element without making complex queries.

However when we read or write complex type containing subtype with `@DocumentID` properties all their values are replaced with the root type's `@DocumentID` property.

Documentation says - it is intended.

> When writing a Codable object containing an @DocumentID annotated field, its value is ignored. This allows you to read a document from one path and write it into another without adjusting the value here.

What are options on dealing with the issue except for creating new subtypes without `@DocumentID` property for storing them inside collection's element type?

Supplement: I'm trying to follow the [sample suggested by Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping). In the example provided let's suppose we need to store `Tag` in collection and display and edit all actual tags via list. This leads us to adding `@DocumentID var id` to the `Tag`. But when we try to save `Tag` inside a `Book` `Tag`s `id` are replaced with `Book`s `id` which is not what we want. Important thing is that since tags can be edited we do need to store their full copy (not just id, reference) to ensure correctness.

Comment: You can use DocumentReference as a type instead of Item, then have a collection of Items and a collection of CartElement. Btw That UUID code is irrelevant, it isn’t used by firebase.

Comment: The case is I already have collections of `Item` and `CartElement`. I need to store instance of one type inside and instance of another. Storing reference (`id`) only would be a great decision @Lorem, but the `Item` instance is changeable and we need a snapshot.
As for UUID code. This pattern is used by Peter Friese (peterfriese.dev) because in many cases we need instance `id` before it is saved to Firerstore. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432255
Later we ensure the` id` is kept. As in `updateOrAddItem()`

Comment: I didn’t say ID I said DocumentReference as a type, you can get a snapshot from that just like your would from any other reference.

Comment: @DocumentID id actually bridges DocumentReference and allows for getting and saving documents by some handle. What I'd like to is to store full fledged instances of one type inside another *automatically* just by using `Codable`, @Lorem.

Comment: This is the inherent problem with using such an abstracted API such as this, you don't have any control over the implementation. Consider if the nested `@DocumentID` was not overwritten by its parent and it worked fine for you, until a breaking change in a future update because they changed their minds. For something as relatively complex as this, I'd feel much more comfortable as the engineer not using an abstraction here and doing all of the mapping manually with my own defined rules. Don't use this API simply because it looks cleaner if you're losing functionality and future safety.

Comment: That isn’t possible, it isn’t how databases work.

Comment: I agree, @trndjc. In this particular case however I was so happy with `Codable` abstraction until I ran into this issue. So type safe, so less code. I stick to default `Up to Next Major` version option when add SPM. This is not a guarantee against breaking changes but hopefully library maintainers follow the conventions.

Comment: You can achieve the same type safety without it. Granted, there is more code, but you can create your own abstraction and use the same one-liners throughout the app. As someone who (a) loves to program and (b) is a total control freak, I would opt for creating my own, custom abstraction with my own custom Swift property wrappers. It would be fun, and way more satisfying!