# What are the differences between FirebaseFirestore and FirebaseFirestoreSwift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know with FFS I can use @DocumentID and @ServerTimestamp in my Codable objects.

Is there documentation somewhere?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224399/is-there-firebasefirestoreswift-documentation) to that question, but the answer just says "FirebaseFirestoreSwift is just a wrapper for Firestore"... but that's not accurate, as if I don't import FirebaseFirestoreSwift I can no longer user the attributes listed above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can manually set the id and the server timestamp, without using the propertywrapper

Comment: The `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` framework is mysterious and confusing to everyone because it doesn't even appear to be official even though it is. It was slid in under the rug at some point in the middle of the night without any mention, still without documentation, which is why I don't use it or know much about it.

Comment: I am with @bxod on this. It was kinda slid into the framework with a mention only in the release notes. I don't think there is any official documentation; however, I addressed it in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021668/error-when-trying-to-call-setdatafrom-in-the-cloud-firestore-ios-api-how-ca/61028935#61028935) which also includes a link to a fantastic article on using Codable in Firebase

Answer (score 4):

I found this on cocoapods.org under the installation when researching the same question:

"Where available, it's recommended to install any libraries with a Swift suffix to get the best experience when writing your app in Swift."

https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseFirestore#swift-package-manager

Specifically, FirestoreSwift adds async/await syntax, codable protocol, and property wrappers by utilizing Swift's language features. You can read the source here.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/Firestore/Swift/Source

Peter Friese's blog is also very helpful when you use Firebase with Swift.

https://peterfriese.dev

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Firebase 10.17.0, there is no longer a difference. Up until Firebase 10.17.0, the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` module was used to *extend* the `FirebaseFirestore` module with API that used Swift-only language features like Codable. This separation was the effect of packaging challenges faced when trying to create a mixed language API surface for a single namespace (e.g. FirebaseFirestore).

Now, in Firebase 10.17.0 and later, the `FirebaseFirestore` module contains all of the API that used to live in `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`. This means depending on the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` is no longer needed to get access to Firestore's Swift-only APIs (Codable, property wrappers, etc.)! For more info on how to migrate, check out the migration guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/swift-migration.

Answer (score 1):

@ncooke3 is right. I saw below comment in the source code as well.

> "All of the public API from `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` can now be accessed through the `FirebaseFirestore` module. Therefore, the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` module is deprecated and will be removed in the future. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/swift-migration for migration instructions."

Reference:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseFirestoreSwift/Sources/FirebaseFirestoreSwift.swift#L16