# Do I need to install pod Firebase/Firestore if I have FirebaseFirestoreSwift installed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to run app with only FirebaseFirestoreSwift installed and it works as intended. But I'm trying to find a clear answer to this question because the most of the sources, tutorials or code examples have pod 'Firebase/Firestore' and pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift' both included in project's podfile.

Comment: What is 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift' and where does it come from?

Comment: It's a CocoaPods library https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseFirestoreSwift

Comment: I have Firebase/Core and Firebase/Firestore to use Firestore.

Comment: @ElTomato The FirebaseFirestoreSwift was stealth introduced a couple of years ago to better handle mapping of Firestore data. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021668/error-when-trying-to-call-setdatafrom-in-the-cloud-firestore-ios-api-how-ca/61028935#61028935) and please take a look at the article from Peter Friese (linked in the answer) as it's got all the info you need. Also Firebase/core is no longer needed - see [Available Pods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods). OP, please include the Firebase/Firestore in your podfile per the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`'s `podspec` (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseFirestoreSwift.podspec), you'll see it lists `FirebaseFirestore` as a dependency. So, no, you don't have to explicitly include it yourself -- it'll get installed as a dependency by the system when you install `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`.

---

For further information you can keep a check on the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) where various updates in the versions and bug fixes have been explained briefly.

*(See comments below for a discussion about whether it is a stylistically good choice to include the dependencies explicitly)*

Comment: Agreed, that it's not technically necessary since FirebaseFirestore is a dependency of FirebaseFirestoreSwift. However, it is often considered good style to avoid relying on transitive dependencies and be explicit about the inclusion of required dependencies.

Comment: That’s going to be quite a list if one also includes all of the Firestore dependencies explicitly (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseFirestore.podspec).

Comment: Most app's don't depend directly on Firestore's dependencies, but an app using FirebaseFirestoreSwift API's is also typically using API's from FirebaseFirestore - but not grpc or absl.

Comment: Added a note in the answer to check the comments to see these notes.