# Swift: How to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in document().setData() Firestore database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

All I want to do is set a Firebase Server Timestamp in `setData()` but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

Here is what I've tried:

```
for document in snapshot!.documents {
    do {
        try document.reference.collection("Data").document()
           .setData(from: ["first" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), "second" : dataStringArray])

        print("Data successfully written to firestore.")
    } catch let error {
        print("Error writing data to firestore: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The intent is to set a serverTimestamp as a field everytime the data is written to get a history of data writes.

It keeps showing the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` so I try to give it some context by casting it to `FieldValue` but then I get the same `ambiguous without more context` issue so I try to cast it to `ServerTimestamp` or `Timestamp` and I get `Cannot convert value of type 'FieldValue' to type 'Timestamp' in coercion`.

It works well in Android to simply do this:

```
document.reference.collection("Data").document().set(FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to formattedDataList)
```

but for some reason it doesn't work in Swift. I've been searching for hours now trying to understand this issue but haven't been able to find a good explanation.

I also tried this:

```
setData(from: [FieldValue.serverTimestamp() : dataStringArray])
```

but I get `Error writing data to firestore: invalidValue([<FSTServerTimestampFieldValue: 0x280412de0>:`

Comment: Are you able to do it without ```"second": dataStringArray``` field?

Comment: On iOS you should use a `Codable` struct to represent your Firestore document.  You can add a [property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestoreswift/api/reference/Structs/ServerTimestamp) for your timeStamp and if it is `nil` then it will be filled in by the server

Comment: @AhmedShendy I can do it without the "second" part but I need the dataStringArray to be included.

Comment: @Paulw11 So all I have to do to set a firebase server timestamp is make it codable? I am not quite sure how to do that. Do you know of any good resources to learn how?

Comment: https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/

Comment: @DylonJaynes, if so, then the issue is with the `dataStringArray`, how this data looks like, I tried to make array of strings in a second field and it worked. Try to make the `dataStringArray` is more clear about its type.

Comment: @AhmedShendy It is an array of varying types such as Int, Double, String, etc. No custom objects though.

Comment: @DylonJaynes Hmm, I have made a test on array of Any, and it works with me .. since it works with you without `dataStringArray`, then you should investigate the issue with `dataStringArray`, for example you can do this `"second": "some string"` and see if this works.

Comment: @AhmedShendy Thanks for the tip but it was actually just an issue with how I was using setData(). I'll post an answer below for others who have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using `setData(from:)` instead of simply using `setData()`

Changing this

`.setData(from: ["first" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), "second" : dataStringArray])`

to this

`.setData(["first" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), "second" : dataStringArray])`

totally fixed my problem.

It appears that I was trying to use an extension intended to simplify crafting custom objects but it wasn't added to the docs for some reason. I was using it wrong because I was trying to use it like what is in the docs.

This StackOverflow Question explains a bit more about the issue. [Error when trying to call setData(from: ) in the Cloud Firestore ios API. How can i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021668/error-when-trying-to-call-setdatafrom-in-the-cloud-firestore-ios-api-how-ca)

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't notice this at all, I think `setData(from: )` requires `from` to be an object Conforming to `Codable` something like this. Yeah, I used `setData()` not `setData(from:)`

Comment: @AhmedShendy Ah, that explains it! Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wanted to write a comment, but due to the limitation not to be able to add code snippets, it became an answer. Please forgive me if it isn't really the answer for you.

In the chat within my app I am using Date as a sendDate (see example from my code below), wouldn't that an option for you?

```
func addNewChatMessageFromData( _ id: String,
                                _ chatId: String,
                                _ messageText: String,
                                _ messageType: String,
                                _ usersIds: [String],
                                _ senderId: String,
                                _ senderName: String,
                                _ lastSenderImageLink: String,
                                _ sendDate: Date
) {
    do {
        
        let chatMessageRef = db.collection("chatMessages").document().documentID
        
        let newChatMessage = ChatMessageFB(chatMessageRef, chatId, messageText, messageType, usersIds, senderId, senderName, lastSenderImageLink, sendDate)
        
        try db.collection("chatMessages").document(chatMessageRef).setData(from: newChatMessage) { _ in
            print("Successful writing ChatMessage to Firestore")
        }
        
        
    } catch let error {
        print("Error writing ChatMessage to Firestore: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Best, Sebastian

Comment: `serverTimeStamp` has the server fill in the timeStamp, independent of the date/time on your device.

Comment: @Paulw11, That's right, sorry I didn't take that into account